# WebElement click intercepted by itself

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm receiving an `ElementClickInterceptedException` when trying to click on a button. Normally I would be able to handle this, but the curious thing is that the 'intercepting' element is the same element as the one I'm trying to click, as seen here:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <button type="button" name="button" class="vs-component vs-button vs-button-success vs-button-filled includeIcon includeIconOnly vs-radius small">...</button> is not clickable at point (220, 72). Other element would receive the click: <button type="button" name="button" class="vs-component vs-button vs-button-warning vs-button-filled includeIcon includeIconOnly vs-radius small">...</button>
```

I have checked the button in devTools using the selector:

```
button[class='vs-component vs-button vs-button-warning vs-button-filled includeIcon includeIconOnly vs-radius small']
```

Sure enough, there is exactly one element on the page with that selector.
What is going on here?
I am using chromedriver 95.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the your selector is wrong in your code. you are trying to click on warning button but it is blocked by success button.

Comment: You are absolutely right, my bad. The issue still stands, though. Both buttons are next to each other and do not overlap at any point, but I still receive an `ElementClickInterceptedException`.

Comment: may be you can try with alternate methods like actions class click method or javascript executor method

Comment: I have just tried it with an Actions class click; it now clicks the button to the right of the desired button. When I check the buttons in devTools they still do not seem to overlap though.